# Using _Generic for printf formatting

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I find myself often entering in the wrong formatting type, and not remembering when to do `f` or `Lf` or `lf`, etc. Is there a way to do something like the following with the help of the `_Generic` keyword?

```
#define TYPE(X)   _Generic((X), float: "float", double: "double", long double: "long_double")
#define FORMAT(X) _Generic((X), float: "%f",    double: "%f",     long double: "%Lf")

printf("%s if of type %s\n", FORMAT(10.), 10., TYPE(10.));
```

Basically, I want it to print:

> 10.000000 is of type double

Is there a way to do that?

I suppose one shorthand option would be doing something like:

```
#define TYPE(X)     _Generic((X), float: "float", double: "double", long double: "long_double")
#define STRINGIZE(X)   #X
printf("%s if of type %s\n", STRINGIZE(10.), TYPE(10.));
```

> 10. if of type double

Comment: The majority of popular compilers have the ability to parse a literal format string, and can warn you about type mismatches. It's more worthwhile to enable that instead of messing with macros.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica sure but this also provides nice documentation for myself where I can see all type formats in one place.

Comment: The requirement to repeat `10.` 3 times seems like a downside to this thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format specifiers in `printf` can't be made parameters by themselves.  They need to be part of the format string.

You can do this by making the `FORMAT` macro the entire format string for one call to `printf` just to print the value.  Then you can have another call for the rest:

```
printf(FORMAT(10.), 10.);
printf(" is of type %s\n", TYPE(10.));
```

But, as was stated in the comments, modern compilers are smart enough to detect mismatches between `printf` format strings and their arguments.  So relying on that works just as well.

Comment: how about combining it into: `#define PPRINT(X)   printf(FORMAT(X), X); printf(" is of type %s\n", TYPE(X))` `PPRINT(10.);`. Are there any downsides to doing it like that?

Answer (score 1):

> wrong formatting type, and not remembering when to do f or Lf or lf, etc.

Note that for `float` and `double`, `l` or not `l` are valid as `float` augments  to a `...` parameter are promoted to `double`.  The `l` is optional with `printf` specifier  `"%f"`,  and friends: `fFeEgGaA`.

```
printf("%f\n", 1.2f);
printf("%f\n", 3.4);
printf("%lf\n", 5.6f); // unusual, yet OK
printf("%lf\n", 7.8);
```

---

To use `_Generic` for printing, perhaps [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485).

A useful reason to use different print specifiers for `float/double` is precision.

```
#define ForD(X)   _Generic((X), float: FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, double: DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1)
printf("%.*e\n", ForD(f), f);  // Best if `f` is not be an expression.
```

Comment: that's pretty neat -- could you please explain a bit how the `ForD(X)` works? Does that specify the precision, such as `%.4f` based on the `FLT|DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` and then what does the `*e` do?

Comment: @carl.hiass `... "*e", precession, fp_value);` prints `fp_value` in exponential notation with `precession` digits to the right as in sd.dddddd...dddesdd  (s: sign, d: digit).  `float` informative up to about 9 digits, `double` to 17.  Research `printf()` for details.